# SQL Subquery as expression

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following two tables:

```
Create Table #Claims (ClaimId int, FormType varchar(3), AdjustmentVersion int)

Create Table #Secondary (FeeId int, FeeName varchar(60))
```

I want to be able to return all the claims that are a specific FormType and AdjustmentVersion.

Given the following query:

```
select * from #Claims where FormType = 'DEN' and AdjustmentVersion in (1,2,3,(select FeeId from #Secondary))
```

How do I correct the syntax to match the AdjustmentVersion on the given integers and the subquery at the same time? Currently, I am getting error 'Subquery returned more than one result'.

I tried using and OR with AdjustmentVersion but that ended up ignoring the FormType = 'DEN'

Comment: `I tried using and OR with AdjustmentVersion but that ended up ignoring the FormType = 'DEN'` You must have missed out the `parenthesis`. Use `(  )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the values into two sets, the literals and the subquery:

```
select *
  from #Claims
  where FormType = 'DEN' and
    ( AdjustmentVersion in (1,2,3) or AdjustmentVersion in (select FeeId from #Secondary) );
```